# Determine if the student has passing grades

Tags: java

I made a program in Java that asks for the student's name, course, and grades. After the required text inputs are filled, the program will then show the result. If the student passed, the program will show "PASSED"; if the student is failing, the program will show "ACADEMIC WARNING"; if the student failed, the program will show "FAILED".

So this is the code:

```
/*
 * Java Grades by fosionef
 */


import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaGrades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getStudentName();
        getStudentCourse();
        getGrades();
    }


    // get student name
    public static void getStudentName() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Name: ");
        //String name = input.nextLine();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name: " + name.toUpperCase());
    }


    // get student course
    public static void getStudentCourse() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String course = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input Course: ");
        //String course = input.nextLine();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Course: " + course.toUpperCase());
    }


    // get student grades
    public static void getGrades() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double grades = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input grades: "));
        //double grades = input.nextDouble();

        if(grades == 90 || grades >= 80) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grades + ": PASSED!");
        }else if(grades == 79 || grades >= 75) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, grades + ": ACADEMIC WARNING!");
        }else if(grades <= 74) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,grades + ": FAILED!");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input the required");
        }
    }
}
```

How was the code? I am looking forward to corrections and suggestions. That way I can improve my coding skills. Thank you.

Comment: Please do not change the code after the code has been review, once the code has been received everyone needs to look at the same code, here are the [site guidelines on this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Reduce code repetition / redundant checks

Your `if` statements are redundant. If `grade = 90`, it already satisfies the `grade >= 80`, so just use that. No need to check if it equals `90` exactly because that's already covered.

Instead of having four different lines where you show a message dialog, have a string that you assign the message to and print that at the end? Something like this:

```
String message;
if (grades >= 80) {
    message = grades + ": Passed!";
} else if (grades >= 75) {
    message = grades + ": Academic Warning!";
} else {
    message = grades + ": Failed!";
}
JOptionPage.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

## Reduce unused code

You created a `Scanner` in all of your functions, but never use them. I'd remove them for code clarity.

Comment: @RolandIllig Wrote this while working so it was more of a rough draft than anything. And yeah working with python for so long then reviewing a java project caused a few mistakes lol.

Comment: The last "else if" should not have the "if". The fact that `(grades < 75)` is clear from the former two ifs failing, and the reader does not have to ask himself whether there's a case that has not been covered.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Linny's answer, I can comment on the following topics:

1. Use correct method names. `getGrades` method gets grade input and displays student's status. You should name it accordingly. Actually, your `getGrades` method does **two** different things which is a violation of [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Dividing it into two methods such as `getGrades` and `displayResult` could be a better solution.
2. Try to handle exceptions. While getting grade input, you tried to cast it to double. However, user input might not be converted to double (For example: supply 'a' as input) after which `NumberFormatException` is thrown. You should not ignore such errors/exceptions.
3. Avoid writing duplicate code. `getStudentName` and `getStudentCourse` methods are doing almost the same thing. Defining a common method for this purpose can reduce code repetition.

Comment: A "magic" number that can be readily understood from the context is in no way magic, it is just a number. And there is no rule against using numbers in code. If anything, the source of these numbers should be mentioned in the code. Using constants only does harm in this case.

Comment: I agree with you that using constants might be overkill in this case. The answer is edited accordingly.